# Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, union

how can i use **union** and **order by** in mysql ?

```
select * from _member_facebook 
inner join _member_pts 
ON _member_facebook._fb_owner=_member_pts._username 
where _member_facebook._promote_point = 9 
ORDER BY RAND() limit 2 
UNION ALL
select * from _member_facebook 
inner join _member_pts 
ON _member_facebook._fb_owner=_member_pts._username 
where _member_facebook._promote_point = 8 limit 3
```

give me error

```
#1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY
```

any one can help ?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Try with:

```
(
  select 
    * 
  from 
     _member_facebook 
   inner join 
     _member_pts 
   ON 
     _member_facebook._fb_owner=_member_pts._username 
  where 
    _member_facebook._promote_point = 9 
  ORDER BY RAND() 
  limit 2
) 
UNION ALL
(
  select 
    * 
  from 
    _member_facebook 
   inner join 
    _member_pts 
   ON 
     _member_facebook._fb_owner=_member_pts._username 
  where 
    _member_facebook._promote_point = 8 
  limit 3
)
```

Although, I think you should put the `ORDER BY` clause at the end of the second query

Answer (score 36):

With parenthesis:

```
(
    SELECT *
    FROM _member_facebook
    INNER JOIN _member_pts
    ON _member_facebook._fb_owner         =_member_pts._username
    WHERE _MEMBER_FACEBOOK._PROMOTE_POINT = 9
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 2
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT *
    FROM _MEMBER_FACEBOOK
    INNER JOIN _MEMBER_PTS
    ON _MEMBER_FACEBOOK._FB_OWNER         =_MEMBER_PTS._USERNAME
    WHERE _MEMBER_FACEBOOK._PROMOTE_POINT = 8
    LIMIT 3
)
```

Said that, it isn't mandatory for MySQL to keep the inner sorting in the outer clause—though it'll *probably* do so since it needs to sort rows anyway to calculate the corresponding `LIMIT` clauses.

Comment: yeah, I was missing the parenthesis too, and adding it fixed it

Answer (score 30):

#### Explanation:

It's important to understand how this works to avoid "gotchas" in similar use cases. Note that`union`'s syntax is somewhat "special":

> <sub>*substatement*</sub> `union all` <sub>*substatement*</sub> `union all` <sub>*substatement*</sub> [`order by`-clause] [`limit`-clause]

where "*substatement*" can optionally be surrounded by `(` and `)`. Some working examples:

- ```
  select 1 union all (select 2);
  select 1 union all  select 2  union all (select 3);
  select 1 union all (select 2) union all  select 3;
  select 1 union all (select 2) union all (select 3);
  select 1 union all (select 2) union all (select 3) union all  select 4;
  select 1 union all (select 2) union all  select 3  union all (select 4);
  ```

**However**, if you surround the first "*substatement*" with braces, you **must** surround all the other "*substatement*"s with braces:

- ```
  (select 1) union all (select 2) union all (select 3);
  ```

(Note that the above point is not mentioned in the [official docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html).)

Failing to do that is a syntax error:

- ```
  mysql> (select 1) union all select 2; -- error because not all "substatement"s are braced
  ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the...
  mysql> (select 1) union all (select 2) union all  select 3; -- error because not all "substatement"s are braced
  ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error...
  mysql> (select 1) union all  select 2  union all (select 3); -- error because not all "substatement"s are braced
  ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error...
  ```

Next, each "*substatement*" can contain `where`, `group by`, `having`, `join`, `limit`, but not `order by`.

If you'd like to use `order by`, the "*substatement*" that contains `order by` must be surrounded by braces. (Which means they are no longer optional.)

Now, if we'd look at the syntax again:

> <sub>*substatement*</sub> `union all` <sub>*substatement*</sub> `union all` <sub>*substatement*</sub> [`order by`-clause] [`limit`-clause]

we can see that the entire `union` statement ends with an optional `order by` / `limit`. These two keywords apply to the entire `union` statement, not just the last "*substatement*":

- ```
  mysql> select 1
      -> union all
      -> select 2 limit 1;
  +---+
  | 1 |
  +---+
  | 1 |
  +---+
  1 row in set (0.00 sec)

  mysql>
  ```

We've mentioned previously that the `limit` keyword can also be applied to individual "*substatement*"s:

- ```
  mysql> select 1 limit 1
      -> union all
      -> select 2;
  +---+
  | 1 |
  +---+
  | 1 |
  | 2 |
  +---+
  2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

  mysql>
  ```

If you want to apply `limit` to the last "*substatement*" (as opposed to the entire `union` statement), you **must** surround the last "*substatement*" with braces:

- ```
  mysql> select 1
      -> union all
      -> (select 2 limit 1);
  +---+
  | 1 |
  +---+
  | 1 |
  | 2 |
  +---+
  2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

  mysql>
  ```

To apply `limit` to the the last "*substatement*" **and also**  to the entire `union` statement, use:

- ```
  mysql> select 1
      -> union all
      -> (select 2 limit 1)limit 1;
  +---+
  | 1 |
  +---+
  | 1 |
  +---+
  1 row in set (0.00 sec)

  mysql>
  ```

It's the same with `order by`:

- ```
  mysql> select 1
      -> union all
      -> (select 2 order by 1)order by 1;
  +---+
  | 1 |
  +---+
  | 1 |
  | 2 |
  +---+
  2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

  mysql>
  ```

But note that applying `order by` to "*substatement*"s is *meaningless* because the docs have explicitly **stated** that `order by` is only guaranteed ([cf.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26372511/632951)) to work when applied to the entire `union` statement:

> [–§–](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)  ..use of `ORDER BY` for individual `SELECT` statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result..

The only way `order by` would make sense in a "*substatement*" is if you combine it with `limit`:

> [–§–](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)  ..the use of ORDER BY in this context is typically in conjunction with `LIMIT`, so that it is used to determine the subset of the selected rows to retrieve for the `SELECT`, even though it **does not** necessarily affect the order of those rows in the final `UNION` result.

Also, if you want to combine [`select into`](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql%20select%20into) with `union`, there'll be more "gotchas" to watch out for. See [issue 32858](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=32858#c145782) regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

Using parentheses fixed my problem while using Order by and limit clauses in the query. My requirement was to get the top and the bottom row in the table with a certain condition and the following code worked for me:

```
(SELECT column1, column2
FROM table1
ORDER BY column1, column2
LIMIT 1)

UNION

(SELECT column1, column2
FROM table2
ORDER BY column1, column2 
LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct is:

```
(SELECT *
   FROM _member_facebook
   INNER JOIN _member_pts ON _member_facebook._fb_owner=_member_pts._username
   WHERE _member_facebook._promote_point = 9 LIMIT 2)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT *
   FROM _member_facebook
   INNER JOIN _member_pts ON _member_facebook._fb_owner=_member_pts._username
   WHERE _member_facebook._promote_point = 8 LIMIT 3)
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try () i think like

```
(SELECT  CITY,LENGTH(CITY) FROM STATION WHERE LENGTH(CITY)=(SELECT MIN(LENGTH(CITY)) FROM STATION) ORDER BY CITY LIMIT 1) 
UNION ALL
(SELECT  CITY,LENGTH(CITY) FROM STATION WHERE LENGTH(CITY)=(SELECT MAX(LENGTH(CITY)) FROM STATION) ORDER BY CITY LIMIT 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think use of parenthesis is mandatory if you use order by or limit or both. I tried working on a query by using limit and order by interchangeably without parenthesis and the query did not work. It only worked after adding parenthesis.