# MySQL/MariaDB - order by inside subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, sql-order-by, mariadb

I used the following query with MySQL 5.5 (or previous versions) for years without any problems:

```
SELECT t2.Code from (select Country.Code from Country order by Country.Code desc ) AS t2;
```

The order of the result was always descending as I needed.

Last week, I just migrated to a new MySQL Version (In fact, I migrated to MariaDB 10.0.14) and now the same query with the same database is not sorted descending anymore. It is sorted ascending (or sorted using the natural order, not sure in fact).

So, can somebody could tell me if this is a bug or if this is a change of the behaviour in recent versions of MySQL/MariaDB?

Comment: Possibly relevant:  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/group-by-trick-has-been-optimized-away/

Comment: MySQL<>MariaDB, ask about 1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is order by clause allowed in a subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101908/is-order-by-clause-allowed-in-a-subquery)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

After a bit of digging, I can confirm both your scenarios:

MySQL 5.1 does apply the `ORDER BY` inside the subquery.

MariaDB 5.5.39 on Linux does *not* apply the `ORDER BY` inside the subquery when no `LIMIT` is supplied. It *does* however correctly apply the order when a corresponding `LIMIT` is given:

```
SELECT t2.Code 
FROM (
  SELECT Country.Code FROM Country ORDER BY Country.Code DESC LIMIT 2
) AS t2;
```

Without that `LIMIT`, there isn't a good reason to apply the sort inside the subquery. It can be equivalently applied to the outer query.

#### Documented behavior:

As it turns out, [MariaDB has documented this behavior](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/faq/general-faq/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/) and it is not regarded as a bug:

> A "table" (and subquery in the `FROM` clause too) is - according to the SQL standard - an unordered set of rows. Rows in a table (or in a subquery in the `FROM` clause) do not come in any specific order. That's why the optimizer can ignore the `ORDER BY` clause that you have specified. In fact, SQL standard does not even allow the `ORDER BY` clause to appear in this subquery (we allow it, because `ORDER BY ... LIMIT` ... changes the result, the set of rows, not only their order).
>
> You need to treat the subquery in the `FROM` clause, as a set of rows in some unspecified and undefined order, and put the `ORDER BY` on the top-level `SELECT`.

So MariaDB also recommends applying the `ORDER BY` in the outermost query, or a `LIMIT` if necessary.

Note: I don't currently have access to a proper MySQL 5.5 or 5.6 to confirm if the behavior is the same there (and SQLFiddle.com is malfunctioning). [Comments on the original bug report](https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-3926) (closed as not-a-bug) suggest that MySQL 5.6 probably behaves the same way as MariaDB.

Comment: @Michael, It is **typical** for `order by` not to apply inside a subquery isn't it? I don't think any db would guarantee that ordering.

Comment: @Pacerier As noted in the quoted docs "_SQL standard does not even allow the ORDER BY clause to appear in this subquery_", so most RDBMS probably won't allow it.

Comment: There is no other way to have this work without sort working in a sub query.

`SELECT sq.*, group_concat(tg.group_id) as group_ids
 FROM (SELECT t.id, t.query, t.serial_no FROM tokens t WHERE t.changed_at > ? AND t.serial_no > ? ORDER BY t.serial_no ASC LIMIT ?) sq
   LEFT JOIN token_groups tg ON sq.id = tg.token_id GROUP BY sq.id`

Without the limited result in the subquery, the outer query is very costly (due to the aggregating function)

Comment: Result sets have order per an order by, tables have no row order. No ordering is guaranteed for an inner select with an order by. [Is order by clause allowed in a subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2101908/3404097)
 [Order Of Execution of the SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4596739/3404097)

Comment: @RaviSanwal See my comment above. "There is no other way to have this work without sort working in a sub query." There are queries for the desired result, but they don't involve nested ORDER BY without LIMIT, and no row order is guaranteed or meaningful for a nested ORDER BY without or after LIMIT. "is very costly" You have no sound reason to believe that. You have an unjustified & incorrect mental model of DBMS execution. A particular DBMS, version & query has a certain plan; a DBMS version might publish (nonstandard) implementation guarantees.

Comment: I guess I should put a disclaimer. My observations were based on MySQL 5.7 and the queries produced different results. The one above and where we directly join the two tables and put the order and limit outside. This could be a DBMS implementation thing. Some other DBMS could logically infer that there is a sort and limit on a table so would automatically reduce the results before joining and aggregating but MySQL doesn't do that. (Or rather didn't do it), thus we had to move the order and limit into the subquery. Order is indeed guaranteed in a subquery when LIMIT is provided. Again, MySQL.

Comment: @RaviSanwal What is not guaranteed by the documentation is not guaranteed. Your idiosyncratic theory has no justification. Some results from some runs justify nothing, including re reruns of the same inputs. The semantics does not involve any ordering other than before the LIMIT, which produces an unordered set of rows. You fundamentally misunderstand the semantics. PS See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify 1 non-sole non-poster commenter `x` per comment about that comment.

Answer (score 5):

In newer versions of MySQL and MariaDB you can force the ORDER BY in a sub query by applying a LIMIT. If you don't want to limit the rows, use the biggest number of BIGINT as a LIMIT.

This may come in handy at times, when the sub query needs to be generated in a desired order, for applying line numbers, for example.

Comment: I think this "trick" has been shown to fail in obscure cases.

Answer (score -1):

Use order + limit insert subquery like this :

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM some_table 
  ORDER BY date DESC
  LIMIT 0,18446744073709551615
) AS a GROUP BY person
;
```

It will keep the order before grouping.

Comment: This adds nothing to answers already here, such an answer should not  be posted. Also this question is a duplicate, so it should be closed & not answered.

Comment: No, there is no guarantee it will keep the order. See my comments at the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372511/mysql-mariadb-order-by-inside-subquery/75945788#comment133967330_26372638