# MySQL - ORDER BY with part of UNION

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, mariadb, union

for long time i have used this method to order my lists (for html selects):

```
SELECT '' AS ID, '' AS Name UNION 
SELECT ID, Name FROM (SELECT ID, Name FROM myTable ORDER BY Name) AS myTableTmp
```

but after update to new MySQL(MariaDB) version i find out, this sorting is not working anymore. Like explained here it conflicts with SQL standart: [mysql - order by inside subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372511/mysql-order-by-inside-subquery)

What is best practice to get desired order?
Or should i use easy way, and add `LIMIT 65000` to nested query?

**Edit:**

Well, my original example was not precise enough, so people was able to misunderstood me.
Here is corrected example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myTable` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;


INSERT INTO `myTable` (`ID`, `Name`) VALUES
(1, 'Banana'),
(2, 'Apple'),
(3, NULL);
```

If i select in old version:

```
SELECT '0' AS ID, '-' AS Name UNION 
SELECT ID, Name FROM (SELECT ID, Name FROM myTable ORDER BY Name) AS myTableTmp
```

I get:

```
0   -
3   NULL
2   Apple
1   Banana
```

How i get same result in new MySQL versions?

Comment: A order by in the outer query would be the most easy.

Comment: But i want first part of union stay on top no matter what. Will `SELECT '' AS ID, '' AS Name UNION 
SELECT ID, Name FROM myTable ORDER BY Name` order all rows, or even give error? I remember there was issues with this, at least ~8 years ago...

Comment: ORDER BY at the end is giving order (3, 0, 2, 1), i need order (0, 3, 2, 1) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, most clean SQL only solution at the momet is as here 
[Using union and order by clause in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531251/using-union-and-order-by-clause-in-mysql)

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM (
SELECT '0' AS ID, '-' AS Name, 1 AS Rank UNION 
SELECT ID, Name, 2 AS Rank FROM myTable
) AS myTableTmp ORDER BY Rank, Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Or else you can move the order by outside:

```
SELECT 
    ID, Name
FROM
    (SELECT '' AS ID, '' AS Name UNION SELECT 
        ID, Name
    FROM
        yourTable) AS yourTableTmp
ORDER BY Name;
```

Comment: That's exactly what i am trying to avoid - i want `SELECT '' AS ID, '' AS Name` be out of `ORDER BY` and always be first row.

Comment: Sorry if I'm understanding it wrong:

You want 
**"<EMPTY_ID>", "<EMPTY_NAME>"** 
to be on top of the HTML select, but you don't want to apply
**ORDER BY** to **"<EMPTY_ID>", "<EMPTY_NAME>"**
with selected rows?

Can you add more detail?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ORDER BY CASE ... END` to change the defualt sorting behavior to get the expected result.

How it works

All '-' values get postion "1" within the ORDER BY 
All NULL values get position "2" within the ORDER BY 
 
All names get position "3+" and sorted on alphabet.

**Query**

```
SELECT '0' AS ID, '-' AS Name UNION 
SELECT ID, Name FROM (
  SELECT
     ID
   , Name
  FROM
   myTable
) AS myTableTmp
ORDER BY
 CASE 
  WHEN 
   Name = '-'
  THEN
   1
  WHEN 
   Name IS NULL
  THEN
   2
  ELSE 
   Name
 END
```

see demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xcy45sUEDKN9gJhNpVqoHd/2

> But what if someone put name '-' in table? i may get the wrong id in
>   that case...

**Query**

```
SELECT
   '0' AS ID
 , '-' AS Name
 , 0 AS position

UNION

SELECT
   ID
 , Name
 , CASE
     WHEN 
      Name IS NULL
     THEN 
      2
     ELSE
      3
   END AS position
FROM (
   SELECT
       ID
     , Name
   FROM
    myTable 
) AS myTableTmp

ORDER BY 
   position
 , name ASC
```

see demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xcy45sUEDKN9gJhNpVqoHd/7

Comment: But what if someone put name '-' in table? i may get the wrong id in that case...

Comment: "But what if someone put name '-' in table? i may get the wrong id in that case... " i've made a update @Andrei i think the update does a better job handling that case.

Comment: Adding dedicated column for sorting may be one of right directions ... Problem is - my queries usually are big and ugly, if i also start adding CASE, CROSS JOIN and user variables to them, i i will not be able to read them myself :)

Comment: Looking down on it you even don't need to use MySQL user variables for it to work. @Andrei.. The CASE is simply required or you need to break it down into a other UNION.something like this https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xcy45sUEDKN9gJhNpVqoHd/8