# Order by sometimes not work in my query

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I defined two classes:

```
class OrderEntryVacancyRenew(OrderEntry):
    ...
    vacancy_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('vacancy.id'), nullable=False)
    vacancy = db.relationship('Vacancy')
    remaining = db.Column(db.SmallInteger)

class Vacancy(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    renew_at = db.Column(TZDateTime, index=True)
```

Then I defined the method to refresh `OrderEntryVacancyRenew.remaining` and `Vacancy.renew_at`.

```
def renew_vacancy():
    filters = [
        OrderEntryVacancyRenew.remaining,
        Vacancy.status == 0,
        or_(
            Vacancy.renew_at <= (utcnow() - INTERVAL),
            Vacancy.renew_at.is_(None))
    ]

    renew_vacancies = OrderEntryVacancyRenew.query.options(
        load_only('remaining', 'vacancy_id')
    ).order_by(
        OrderEntryVacancyRenew.id
    ).from_self().group_by(
        OrderEntryVacancyRenew.vacancy_id
    ).join(
        OrderEntryVacancyRenew.vacancy
    ).options(
        contains_eager(OrderEntryVacancyRenew.vacancy).load_only('renew_at')
    ).filter(*filters)

    for entry in renew_vacancies:
        entry.vacancy.renew_at = utcnow()
        entry.remaining -= 1

    db.session.commit()
```

I wrote the unit test to check `renew_vacancy`

```
vacancy1 = Vacancy(id=10000)
vacancy2 = Vacancy(id=10001)
db.session.add_all([vacancy1, vacancy2])
vacancy_renew1 = OrderEntryVacancyRenew(
    vacancy_id=vacancy1.id,
    remaining=24)
# make sure vacancy_renew1.id < vacancy_renew2.id
db.session.add(vacancy_renew1)
db.session.commit()
vacancy_renew2 = OrderEntryVacancyRenew(
    vacancy_id=vacancy1.id,
    remaining=8)
vacancy_renew3 = OrderEntryVacancyRenew(
    vacancy_id=vacancy2.id,
    remaining=42)
db.session.add_all((vacancy_renew2, vacancy_renew3))
db.session.commit()

renew_vacancy()
self.assertEqual(
    (vacancy_renew1.remaining, vacancy_renew2.remaining), (23, 8))
```

`renew_vacancies` is order by OrderEntryVacancyRenew id and group by Vacancy id, so I expect it will filter `vacancy_renew1` and `vacancy_renew3`.

I used the following command to run the unit test 100 times:

```
for i in `seq 1 100`; do python test.py; done
```

In some rare situations, it filters `vacancy_renew2` instead of `vacancy_renew1`.
[image]
[image]

Why does it happen that sometimes `order by` does not work as expected?

I try to print `vacancy_renew1.id` and `vacancy_renew2.id` after `renew_vacancy`.

```
...
db.session.commit()
renew_vacancy()
print vacancy_renew1.id
print vacancy_renew2.id
self.assertEqual(
    (vacancy_renew1.remaining, vacancy_renew2.remaining), (23, 8))
...
```

[image]

Comment: I am not totally convinced that `order_by` is not working in your rare error cases. Are you sure that `vacancy_renew1.id < vacancy_renew2.id` really is true every single time in your test? I'm asking because you add `vacancy_renew1` to the same session twice during your test (`db.session.add_all((vacancy_renew1, vacancy_renew2, vacancy_renew3))`) and I don't know exactly what SA does in such a case. Could you print your new object's IDs in the test to make sure your assumption is true? Also, is the minus sign here: `Vacancy(id-10001)` a typo in the example?

Comment: I'm sorry.It is a misteak in `(db.session.add_all((vacancy_renew1, vacancy_renew2, vacancy_renew3)))` when I post this question.In my project, it is `(db.session.add_all((vacancy_renew2, vacancy_renew3)))`.I'm try to print `entry.id` in loop,and result in screen most of is `1, 3` but sometimes is `2, 3`.I even use 'pdb' to trace this bug before `for entry in renew_vacancies:`.And `renew_vacancies.all()` is `[<OrderEntryVacancyRenew 1>, <OrderEntryVacancyRenew 3>]`, but sometimes is `[<OrderEntryVacancyRenew 2>, <OrderEntryVacancyRenew 3>]`. @shmee

Comment: Could you try printing `vacancy_renew1.id` and `vacancy_renew2.id` inside your test, just before or after you call `renew_vacancy()`? This is just guessing, but it might be some rare race condition inside your test session or between the sessions in your test and your update method.

Comment: I add new pic to in my question.@shmee

Comment: A very strange problem indeed. I'm afraid I don't have a real answer here. Maybe examine the [raw query that SA builds and executes in the background](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/sqlexpressions.html) to see if something gets lost or altered in translation. You could also compare the query strings in `renew_vacancy()` between successful and failed tests by printing it to screen or saving it to file during a test run. If still nothing differs, bulk-execute the query on a DB front-end directly, to see if your DB maybe sometimes acts unexpectedly. Sorry, that I can't help more.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does it happen that sometimes ORDER BY does not work as expected?

Given standard SQL, the results of your query are indeterminate, so it is not very valuable to know why it works most of the time and fails rarely. There are two things that make the results vary:

1. Generally [you should not rely on the order of rows of a subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372511/mysql-order-by-inside-subquery) in enclosing queries, even if you apply an ordering. Some database implementations may have additional guarantees, but on others for example [optimizers may deem the ORDER BY unnecessary](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-table-optimization.html) – which MySQL 5.7 and up does, it removes the subquery entirely.
2. Usually databases, such as SQLite and MySQL<sup>1</sup>, that allow selecting non-aggregate items that are not [functionally dependent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency) on, or are not named in the GROUP BY clause, leave it unspecified from which row in the group the values are taken:

   - [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html):

     > ... Otherwise, it is evaluated against a single arbitrarily chosen row from within the group. If there is more than one non-aggregate expression in the result-set, then all such expressions are evaluated for the same row.
   - [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html):

     > ... In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are nondeterministic, which is probably not what you want. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause.

Trying out the query on SQLite failed the assertion on this machine, while on MySQL it passed. This is probably due to implementation of selecting the row from within the group, but you should not rely on such details.

What you seem to be after is a [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) query, or top-1. Not knowing which database you are using here's a somewhat generic way to do just that using an EXISTS subquery expression:

```
renew_alias = db.aliased(OrderEntryVacancyRenew)

renew_vacancies = db.session.query(OrderEntryVacancyRenew).\
    join(OrderEntryVacancyRenew.vacancy).\
    options(
        load_only('remaining'),
        contains_eager(OrderEntryVacancyRenew.vacancy).load_only('renew_at')).\
    filter(db.not_(db.exists().where(
        db.and_(renew_alias.vacancy_id == OrderEntryVacancyRenew.vacancy_id,
                renew_alias.id < OrderEntryVacancyRenew.id)))).\
    filter(*filters)
```

This query passes the assertion on both SQLite and MySQL. Alternatively you could replace the EXISTS subquery expression with a LEFT JOIN and IS NULL predicate.

**P.s.** I suppose you're using some flavour of MySQL and following advice such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12102288/2681632). You should read the commentary on that one as well, since there are many people rightly pointing out the pitfalls. It does not work, at least for MySQL 5.7 and up.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Controllable with the [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) SQL mode setting, enabled by default in MySQL 5.7.5 and up.