# Keep order in WHERE IN (subquery)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem about keeping the order in the subquery with `WHERE IN` clause.

---

I am using this following query with 2 tables listed below.

```
SELECT * FROM user_list WHERE uid IN (
        SELECT uid from user_history ORDER BY timestamp DESC
) LIMIT 5
```

**Table  - user_list**

```
uid name    surname
001 Alpha   Apples
002 Bravo   Butter
003 Charlie Charlie
004 Delta   Duff
005 Echo    Edward
```

**Table - user_history**

```
uid timestamp
003 0000-00-00 00:00:00
001 0000-00-00 00:00:01
005 0000-00-00 00:00:02
```

---

The expected result is (`ORDER BY timestamp DESC`)

```
005 Echo    Edward
001 Alpha   Apples
003 Charlie Charlie
```

But its result as this

```
001 Alpha   Apples
003 Charlie Charlie
005 Echo    Edward
```

The `ORDER BY` clause is ignored and still order by primary key (`uid`).

I am wondering is there any way to keep the order from subquery?

Comment: Since an order in a subquery does not make any sense why move the order by to the outer query?

Comment: According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372511/mysql-order-by-inside-subquery), it depends on your mysql version. Different versions behaves differently. And finally we don't expect your desired result in standard SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need any subquery use join and try like below

```
SELECT ul.* FROM user_list ul join user_history uh
on ul.uid=uh.uid
order by uh.timestamp desc
limit 5
```

subquery `order by` does not have any affect in the main query output

Answer (score 0):

First you have to join the user_history then order it

```
SELECT * FROM user_list WHERE uid IN (
        SELECT user_history.uid from user_history join user_list where  
 user_list .uid = user_history.uid  ORDER BY user_history.timestamp DESC
) LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query can give you desired result.
Use join on two tables and then sort the colums by timestamp in main query.

Sortin inside subquery will give uid sorted inside in clause but main query by default gives sorted by id .

```
SELECT u.uid,  u.name , u.surname FROM user_list u, user_history h  WHERE u.uid IN (
        SELECT uid from user_history 
) and u.uid = h.uid order by h.timestamp desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT ul.*
FROM user_list ul JOIN
     (SELECT uh.uid, MAX(timestamp) as max_timestamp
      FROM user_history uh
      GROUP BY uh.uid
      ORDER BY MAX(timestamp) DESC
      LIMIT 5
     ) uh
     ON ul.uid = uh.uid
ORDER BY max_timestamp DESC;
```

There may be duplicates in `user_history` (quite likely based on the name).  You seem to want the five most recent records.  So, this aggregates the data to get the five most recent records, then joins to `user_list` and returns the rows in descending order by timestamp.