# How to SELECT in MySQL data based on percentage given?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the following query to select question ids in `table_question`:

```
$sql = "SELECT s.question_id
        FROM table_question s
        WHERE s.chapter_id = $chapter_id
        AND s.publish_status = ".PUBLISHED_ACTIVE." AND (
        s.format_type_id = ".QST_TYPE_OBJECTIVE." OR (s.format_type_id = ".QST_TYPE_SHORT_ANSWER." AND s.question_id < 200000 AND s.publish_status = ".PUBLISHED_ACTIVE."))
        ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5";

$obj_question_ids = DB::connection('mysql_question')->select(DB::raw($sql));
```

In my database, I got ***133010 of objective questions*** and ***15031 subjective questions***. Now, how I can make sure the ratio of my question selection will be

70% Objectives questions and 30% questions will be structure questions?

Comment: How do you get 70% out of 5 returned rows?

Comment: The limit will be 5 questions only per chapter

Comment: As @GordonLinoff says: 70% of 5 answers is 3.5, whcih is impossible. AT BEST you can get 60% - 40 % on 5 answers. And that's the solution, random 3 questions from objective and 2 from subjective.

Comment: @JacquesAmar it seems your answer quite exact what I meant. Now, how to random for 3 question objective and 2 subjective on the same query?

Comment: @ AbuHassan See below. I'm using UNION

Comment: @JacquesAmar I saw it, let me try first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This **might** work

Let's try with parenthesis

[usage of union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732661/incorrect-usage-of-union-and-order-by)

```
   (SELECT s.question_id
            FROM table_question s
            WHERE s.chapter_id = $chapter_id
            AND s.publish_status = ".PUBLISHED_ACTIVE." AND (
            s.format_type_id = ".QST_TYPE_OBJECTIVE." OR (s.format_type_id = ".QST_TYPE_SHORT_ANSWER." AND s.question_id < 200000 AND s.publish_status = ".PUBLISHED_ACTIVE."))
            ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3)
    UNION
    (SELECT s.question_id
            FROM table_question s
            WHERE s.chapter_id = $chapter_id
            AND s.publish_status = ".PUBLISHED_ACTIVE." AND (
            s.format_type_id = ".QST_TYPE_SUBJECTIVE." OR (s.format_type_id = ".QST_TYPE_SHORT_ANSWER." AND s.question_id < 200000 AND s.publish_status = ".PUBLISHED_ACTIVE."))
            ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2)
```