# How to output top 5 from two different dates in the same column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find the best 5 students from 2016 and 2017. My query right now looks like this:

```
SELECT  S.vorname, 
        S.nachname, 
        MAX(I.abgeschlossen) AS Abschlussjahr, 
        A.note
FROM student AS S
INNER JOIN inskription AS I ON S.matnr= I.student
INNER JOIN absolvierung AS A ON S.matnr = A.student
WHERE A.note = 1
AND YEAR(I.abgeschlossen) IN ('2016', '2017')
GROUP BY S.vorname, S.nachname, A.note
ORDER BY Abschlussjahr DESC
```

and the output looks like this:

[picture of my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvGhG.png)

What is a possible way to have the top 5 from 2016 and 2017 in the same column?

Comment: Why do you not simply add `LIMIT 5` to whatever you tried to get the TOP x ?   (How to use that LIMIT is described on this page: [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html))

Comment: @Luuk If i add LIMIT 5 i will only get the results from 2017 but not from 2016. Or is there a way i could achieve this?

Comment: Remove the `ORDER BY Abschlussjahr DESC` ?   But it's pretty unclear from which value you want the get the MAX/TOP, because I do not know what kind of data is in the table `absolvierung`

Comment: @Luuk i'm sorry i didn't ask precisely enough. This is my first time asking a question. So i want the Top 5 Students with the highest dates. 5 students from 2017 and 5 students from 2016, so in total all 10.

Comment: `2016` and `2017` are integers not string. Remove the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should return you the top 5 for both years

```sql
(SELECT S.vorname, 
        S.nachname, 
        I.abgeschlossen AS Abschlussjahr, 
        A.note
FROM student AS S
INNER JOIN inskription AS I ON S.matnr= I.student
INNER JOIN absolvierung AS A ON S.matnr = A.student
WHERE A.note = 1
AND YEAR(I.abgeschlossen) = 2016
ORDER BY Abschlussjahr DESC
LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT S.vorname, 
        S.nachname, 
        I.abgeschlossen AS Abschlussjahr, 
        A.note
FROM student AS S
INNER JOIN inskription AS I ON S.matnr= I.student
INNER JOIN absolvierung AS A ON S.matnr = A.student
WHERE A.note = 1
AND YEAR(I.abgeschlossen) = 2017
ORDER BY Abschlussjahr DESC
LIMIT 5)
```

If you want to `order by` some other columns just change the column name.

Also the `group by` is unnecessary as you don't need the `max()` aggregate function.

---

Edit:
Found on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732661/incorrect-usage-of-union-and-order-by) that you should add parenthesis

Comment: Thank you. But i need them to be in the same table. I can't do two SELECT's sadly.

Comment: It's a `union select` which returns 1 result set

Comment: i get this Error: ERROR: Falsche Eingabe - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY. :(

Comment: @Shmiel TOP 5 is `Microsoft SQL Server` , in `MySQL` you have to use `LIMIT`

Comment: @Ergest Basha Didn't know. Updated.